# Creating objects and putting them into std::list

Tags: c++

I am writing small roguelike game where I spawn some items and put them into the `std::list`. Is this the right way to do it?

The `Item` class is as followed (I know it has public `id` property):

```
class Item {

public:
   Item();
   ~Item();

   unsigned int id;
};
```

Somewhere in the code I also defined:

```
list<Item*> listOfItems;
list<Item*>::iterator it;
```

Now I am using this code to create an item:

```
Item *p = new Item();
p->id = itemCrowbar;
listOfItems.push_back(p);
```

At the end of the program I use small loop to delete all items:

```
for (it = listOfItems.begin(); it!=listOfItems.end(); it++) {
    delete *it;
}
```

Is this approach for creating objects, putting them in `std::list` and
at the end deleting them correct, or am I missing something important here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `Item` has subclasses, then make the `~Item()` destructor virtual.

If `Item` has a copy constructor, and is not a superclass of a subclass, then you can store a copy of the item (not pointer to the item) in the list:

```
list<Item> listOfItems;

Item item;
item.id = itemCrowbar;
listOfItems.push_back(item);
```

In that case, you won't need to delete `Item` pointers before the list is destroyed.

However, if `Item` has subclasses, then this might be legal but a bug (called '[object slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing)'):

```
list<Item> listOfItems;

SubclassOfItem item;
item.id = itemCrowbar;
item.extra = "hello";
listOfItems.push_back(item);
```

Or you can create a list of 'smart pointers' (`std::unique_ptr`) to items: which behave like pointers to `Item`s except that you don't need to delete the `Item` (the `Item` is deleted when the smart pointer which contains it is destroyed).

Comment: Never, ever store `std::auto_ptr` in a container. Further, `auto_ptr` is deprecated, so it shouldn't be used anyway.

Comment: @Yuushi Not even in a std::list? I imagined that list nodes would be immobile.

Comment: "Copying an auto_ptr copies the pointer and transfers ownership to the destination: both copy construction and copy assignment of auto_ptr modify their right hand arguments, and the "copy" is not equal to the original. Because of these unusual copy semantics, auto_ptr may not be placed in standard containers." See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/auto_ptr).

Comment: Item will have subclasses and won't have any copy constructor.

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz Even without a copy-constructor there might (in modern C++) be a [move constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor); but if there are several subclasses then you're right that you need to store by pointer, not by value. **Don't forget to make your destructor virtual**. And consider using a mart pointer to avoid the need to do explicit destruction.

Comment: @ChrisW is "shared_ptr" ok for this job ?

Comment: personally I prefer `pointer container` over a `container of pointers`. The difference is the data is exposed as reference to objects rather than pointers to objects. This makes using the standard algorithms easier. But the advent of lambdas has made this argument slightly (though not entirely) moot. See [boost::ptr_list](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_list.html)

Comment: I have created some small piece of code with shared_ptr and list (I am not sure if it's correct although its working fine) should I post it here of make a new *question* similar to this one for review ?

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz Please post a follow-up question: see [How to post a follow-up question?](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1066/34757)

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not correct.

For such classes, you should do not need to create objects on the heap. This should do :

```
Item p;
p.id = itemCrowbar;
listOfItems.push_back(p);
```

If you add a constructor with a parameter like this ...

```
class Item {

public:
    Item(unsigned int id_):id(id_){}

   unsigned int id;
};
```

... then you could even do this :

```
int main()
{
    std::list<Item> items;

    unsigned int someId = 5;

    items.push_back( {someId} );
}
```

This way you do not have to wory about memory leaks, and you can remove the loop releasing created objects.